# Expand a pandas multi-index with N new levels for each index?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm often in a situation where I have a pandas multi-index with levels like this:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(((1, 2),
                                (1, 3),
                                (2, 2),
                                (2, 5)), names=['hi', 'there'])
a = pd.DataFrame([0]*4, index=ix, columns=['foo'])
```

with this structure:

```
print a
          foo
hi there   
1  2      0
   3      0
2  2      0
   5      0
```

However, I want to expand these indices with, say, 3 new indices per level. So I want to add another index such that the final product looks like this:

```
                  foo
hi there newix     
1  2     1        0
         2        0
   3     1        0
         2        0
2  2     1        0
         2        0
   5     1        0
         2        0
```

I can't think of an obvious way to do this using something like "from_product". I suppose I could construct the tuples manually by iterating through the first two rows, but this seems cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this than I'm thinking of?

edit: ideally this would be something other than, say:

```
newixs = []
for ix in a.index:
    for i in range(5):
        nix = list(ix) + [i]
        newixs.append(nix)
```

This would work (using from_tuples to make the pandas multiindex), but seems hacky to me :P

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use reindexing (with implicit broadcasting) onto your target index ix3:

```
ix3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2),
     (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2),
     (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2),
     (2, 5, 1), (2, 5, 2)],
    names=['hi', 'there', 'newix'])

a.reindex(ix3)    
                   foo
hi  there   newix   
1   2       1      0
            2      0
    3       1      0
            2      0
2   2       1      0
            2      0
    5       1      0
            2      0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first use concat to create a larger DataFrame:

```
In [11]: res = pd.concat([a, a])

In [12]: res
Out[12]: 
          foo
hi there     
1  2        0
   3        0
2  2        0
   5        0
1  2        0
   3        0
2  2        0
   5        0
```

I think the easiest way to append a new index is to add a new column and then `set_index`:

```
In [13]: res['newix'] = np.repeat([1, 2], len(a))

In [14]: res
Out[14]: 
          foo  newix
hi there            
1  2        0      1
   3        0      1
2  2        0      1
   5        0      1
1  2        0      2
   3        0      2
2  2        0      2
   5        0      2

In [15]: res.set_index('newix', append=True)
Out[15]: 
                foo
hi there newix     
1  2     1        0
   3     1        0
2  2     1        0
   5     1        0
1  2     2        0
   3     2        0
2  2     2        0
   5     2        0
```

*Which is basically what you want (you can `res.sort_index()` if needed).*